# Problem with pdflatex command

Tags: pdftex

I don't what's happened but it seems that the usr/texbin directory is not anymore in the system path. When I give the command pdflatex I have command not found. I tried to put the directory on /etc/paths (even if on paths.d/ I have the  TeX directory with the /usr/texbin path) but now when I gave the command pdflatex I have this error:

```
 lstat(./pdflatex) failed ...
./pdflatex: No such file or directory
Assertion failed: (ret), function remove_dots, file ../../../texk/kpathsea/progname.c, line 316.
Abort trap: 6
```

If I enter the command as /usr/texbin/pdflatex everything is ok. All this happened after I installed the haskell environment and pandoc (through cabal). One more thing before installing I changed the permission of the /usr/local/texlive (chown -R 'whoami'...). I am using  Mavericks 10.9.2.

Comment: Fix it. just add export PATH={$PATH}:/usr/texbin to .bash_profile

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem with the OP's system configuration.

Comment: I think this is a problem of Texlive . Because is still not clear why should I had to add line in bash_profile in order to getting the Tex to work properly.

Comment: I had the same problem and I found a strange solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56171314/xelatex-fails-unless-i-re-set-path-to-what-it-already-is This does seem to be a (La)TeX-specific problem.